# SetTimeout only for desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site with a youtube background video (with [YTPlayer](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-ytplayer/)). I am using a CSS spinner that shows while the page is loading. Unfortunately it disappears before the video has loaded and starts playing.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);    
    $('.loader-bg').fadeOut(1000);
    },4000)
    });
```

I added a little timeout, to make sure the video is already playing in the background when fading to the page (I did not know how else that would work, if anyone has an idea, let me know. Would be awesome).

Since I don't need the timeout on a mobile device (I'm just showing a background image), I was wondering if there is an option to say, if you're on desktop > run the timeout, if you're on mobile > don't run it. Is that possible?

**Edit**: My temp workaround with the following code:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{   
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);    
    $('.loader-bg').fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
else
{
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);    
    $('.loader-bg').fadeOut(1000);
    },3000)
    });
}
```

I think there could be a better way though...

Comment: https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki#events `YTPStart` use 
it with `one`, something like `$('#bgndVideo').one("YTPStart",...`

Comment: Define what is mobile and what is desktop?   The lines are not so clear these days.  What is a tablet?  What is a laptop that can convert to a tablet?

Comment: Fixed timeout is not a solution. You need to respond to some reliable "video-ready" event. Suggestion by @eicto looks good.

Answer (score 1):

It think the best way to load a picture as background until the video starts in mb YTPlayer is by applying a css snippet. Please see this article.

[How to load a picture as background until the video starts in mb YTPlayer](http://www.kmbytes.com/how-to-load-a-picture-as-background-until-the-video-starts-in-mb-ytplayer)

It works beautifully for me every time. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the resolution of the display with: `window.screen.availHeight &&
window.screen.availWidth`